# How to declare a "bracket-style" math operator

Tags: math-mode

This has most likely been asked before, but I wasn't able to articulate the question in a way that yielded relevant search results.

How do you declare a math operator to simplify an expression such as `\langle x, y \rangle`? I want to be able to define something like `\innerproduct{x, y}` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to define a macro called, say, `\inprod`. This method automatically declares a companion macro called `\inprod*`, which auto-sizes the angle brackets. The size of the "fences" can be controlled directly as well, by writing `\inprod[\big]{...}`, `\inprod[\Big]{...}`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\inprod\langle\rangle
\begin{document}

$\inprod{a,b}$ 
$\displaystyle \inprod*{\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A variant of the `mathtools` solution, which takes care of empty arguments, with the `xparse` and `etoolbox` packages. It uses  two arguments, separated by a comma; if some argument is empty, it is replaced with a dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
{\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{mm}
{\ifblank{#1}%
{\ifblank{#2}{\,\cdot\,{,}\,\cdot\,}{{\,\cdot \,}{,}{\mkern2mu#2}}}%
{{#1\,}{,}\ifblank{#2}{\,\cdot\,}{\mkern2mu#2}}%
}%

%}%
\begin{document}

\[ \innerp{x, y}, \quad \innerp[\big]{\tfrac{1}{2}x, y} \quad \innerp*{\frac{x}{2}, y}\quad\innerp{x , }\quad \innerp{ , y}\quad \innerp{ , }\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In fact I remember a conversation about precisely this, but it may take me a while to find it. In the meantime:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\iprelay#1,#2{\langle#1,#2\rangle}
\def\ip#1{\iprelay#1}
\begin{document}
\[
\ip{a,b}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\iprelay#1,#2\relax{\langle#1,#2\rangle} \def\ip#1{\iprelay#1\relax}` would be much safer.